# How to stop valgrding while running a CI-Pipeline in Gitlab?

Tags: python, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, valgrind

the main **instance** is in an **infinite loop** waiting for communication commands to afterwords replay this. For the very first step, I would like, somehow, to **stop the dynamic analysis** on this main instance with Valgrind so the **CI on Gitlab** can run until the end without having to cancel it and also having some results, perhaps this result does not tell much. Then as a second step, I would write some special cases that Valgrind could analyze. I'm looking for a workaround for this problem.

Please let me know if I can add some other info about my question.

Comment: Please include your gitlab-ci configuration/scripts

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.